# How to dry in coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, dry

I have the following script:

```
$(".a").click ->
    $("body").animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1500,easing:'easeInOutSine'})

$(".b").click ->
    $("#b").animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1500,easing:'easeInOutSine'})

$(".c").click ->
    $("#c").animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1500,easing:'easeInOutSine'})

$(".d").click ->
    $("#d").animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1500,easing:'easeInOutSine'})
```

I want to make it like so:

```
scroll = animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1500,easing:'easeInOutSine'})

$(".a").click ->
    $("body").scroll

$(".b").click ->
    $("#b").scroll

$(".c").click ->
    $("#c").scroll

$(".d").click ->
    $("#d").scroll
```

but it returns the following error: `animatescroll is not defined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working is because the "scroll" function you're defining is being defined in a variable, while "animatescroll" is a jQuery plugin method.

You can solve this issue the way you want by extending the jQuery object yourself:

```
$.fn.scroll = ->
    this.animatescroll({scrollSpeed:1500,easing:'easeInOutSine'})

$(".a").click ->
    $("body").scroll()

$(".b").click ->
    $("#b").scroll()

$(".c").click ->
    $("#c").scroll()

$(".d").click ->
    $("#d").scroll()
```

It should work. However, I don't recommend this because you're adding a method to the jQuery object with hard-coded parameters, and it may interfere with any jQuery plugins you may have added that already add a "scroll" method to the jQuery object.

The way I'd rather go about solving your issue is to make a variable for the parameter and keep using the animatescroll method, like this:

```
scrollSettings = scrollSpeed:1500, easing:'easeInOutSine'

$(".a").click ->
    $("body").animatescroll scrollSettings

$(".b").click ->
    $("#b").animatescroll scrollSettings

$(".c").click ->
    $("#c").animatescroll scrollSettings

$(".d").click ->
    $("#d").animatescroll scrollSettings
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which approach did you use?

Comment: Why attach four different event handlers if the scroll settings are the same? instead of attaching to `.a`, `.b`,`.c`, and `.d` why not add an additional class to the elements called `.scrollable` and attach the method once?

Comment: I thought the same thing, but the OP wants to apply the scroll method to different elements on each click event (e.g. click on '.a' applies the animatescroll method to 'body', etc).

Answer (score 2):

You're getting "animateScroll is not defined" because it's only defined as a property of the jQuery object ($).
Also, you're defining `scroll` as the result of calling `animateScroll`, not as a function which itself calls `animateScroll`.  You could define it like this:

```
scroll = ($targetEl) ->
    $targetEl.animateScroll({scrollSpeed:1500, easing:'easeInOutsine'})


$(".a").click ->
    scroll $("body")

$(".b").click ->
    scroll $("#b")

$(".c").click ->
    scroll $("#c")

$(".d").click ->
    scroll $("#d")
```

Comment: The `scroll` argument should always be `$(this)`. If it was then you could just say `$('.a, .b, .c, .d').click -> scroll $(this)` but that won't work here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Explain?

Comment: The `.a` click handler is supposed to scroll `body`, not `.a`; the `.b` click handler is supposed to scroll `#b`, not `.b`; ...

Comment: Good catch.  I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You can DRY it up a bit further by doing all the click handler setup in a separate function:

```
makeScroll = (clickSelector, scrollSelector) ->
  $(clickSelector).click -> 
    $(scrollSelector).animatescroll scrollSpeed: 1500, easing: 'easeInOutSine'

makeScroll ".a", "body"
makeScroll ".b", "#b"
makeScroll ".c", "#c"
makeScroll ".d", "#d"
```